# How can I add an hour object to a task using the workfront api?

Tags: rest, workfront-api

I want to write a rest client that will add hours to a particular workfront task. i.e. add more of these:

[image]

[The docs](https://support.workfront.com/hc/en-us/articles/220633507-API-Explorer) are not very clear on this though. They're not very clear on anything TBF, it's just a list of objects with no examples of how to relate them. It's like trying to learn Spanish with just a dictionary!

[image]

I've attempted to do a POST of a new Hour thus:

```
POST https://company.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api/v7.0/hour?apiKey=<api key>
```

Body

```js
{
    "objCode": "HOUR",
    "entryDate": "2018-01-18",
    "hours": 1,
    "status": "SUB",
    "taskID" : "<task id>"
}
```

But all I get back from workfront is:

```js
{
    "data": {
        "objCode": "HOUR",
        "ID": null
    }
}
```

Interestingly if I search for Hours for tasks:

```
GET https://company.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api/v7.0/hour/search?taskID=<task ID>&apiKey=<api key>
```

I get hours back but they don't contain any TaskIds:

```js
{
    "data": [
        {
            "ID": "<id>",
            "objCode": "HOUR",
            "entryDate": "2018-01-16",
            "hours": 3,
            "status": "SUB"
        },
        {
            "ID": "<id>",
            "objCode": "HOUR",
            "entryDate": "2018-01-15",
            "hours": 1,
            "status": "SUB"
        },
        {
            "ID": "<id>",
            "objCode": "HOUR",
            "entryDate": "2018-01-18",
            "hours": 0.75,
            "status": "SUB"
        }
    ]
}
```

Even though [the docs](https://support.workfront.com/hc/en-us/articles/220633507-API-Explorer) state that this object contains a `taskId` field?

Does anyone have any experience of this? How do I add a new Hour to a Task object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. You just need to send a little more data. I'm not sure what the minimum required fields are, but I was able to log 1 hour under a given user for a given task on a given date and have it appear under the task just fine.

```
POST https://x.my.workfront.com/attask/api/v7.0/hour?taskID=<id of task>&ownerID=<user to log hours under>&hours=1.0&entryDate=2017-12-27&apiKey=<key>"
```

Note that instead of TaskID you could pass other valid ID types such as an issue.

Comment: Thanks, [I've fixed now, my content type in my POST was incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48325701/542251). I've tested with and without the OwnerID. Doesn't seem to make a difference. I'm guessing it gets the User from the API key. This is useful to log hours for other users though (yet to test this)

Comment: BTW, this did help because I realised that using the querystring worked, so why didn't my version, which lead to me noticing the incorrect content-type, so thanks